# Hive LLAP tuning: Memory per daemon and Heap Size Calculation

Tags: hive

I am tuning my cluster which has Hive LLAP, According to the below link, https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/215868/hive-llap-deep-dive.html I need to calculate the value of heapsize, but not sure what is the meaning of `*`?

I also have a question regarding how to calculate the value for `hive.llap.daemon.yarn.container.mb` other then then default value given by ambari?

I have tried calculating the value by considering this (`*` as multiplication) and set container value equal to `yarn.scheduler.maximum.allocation.mb`, However **HiveServer 2 interactive** does not start after tuning.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the excellent wiki article for setting up hive llap in HDP suite.
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/149486/llap-sizing-and-setup.html

Your understanding for * is correct, it's used for multiplication.

Rule of thumb here is set `hive.llap.daemon.yarn.container.mb` to  `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` but if your service is not coming up with that value then I would recommend you to change `llap_heap_size` to 80% of `hive.llap.daemon.yarn.container.mb`.